# Caller ID detection on a C# window Application using USR 5637 56K Modem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Following is the code to test the data

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = new    
    System.ComponentModel.Container();
    serialPort1 = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(components);
    serialPort1.PortName = "COM3";
    serialPort1.BaudRate = 115200;
    serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
    serialPort1.Open();
    serialPort1.DataReceived += new 
    SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
}

private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
}
```

The above code reads- "RING" It is correct.
As per the documentation to detect caller ID a command "AT+VCID=1" must be passed. From hyper terminal, I passed this and it is showing me the number correctly.

"DATE:0716
TIME:1311
NMBR:8093000501"

How to pass the command and retrieve only NMBR to a text box.

Comment: Windows already provides TAPI so you *don't* have to write code for each individual modem.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking but i can't find a command that only returns the NMBR.
The quickest solution will be to return the whole string and then just do some simple c# magic to return only the NMBR to a variable.